# How to format Ansible output

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I want to format Ansible output from:

```
my_local | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
116G

my_local2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
116G
```

to

```
my_local >> 116G
my_local2 >> 116G
```

Is it possible?

**`inventory.ini`**:

```
my_local ansible_connection=local
my_local2 ansible_connection=local
```

**Bash command**:

```
ansible all -i inventory.ini -u root -m shell -a "df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print \$4}'"
```

Comment: Having said that you may probably want to try Zabbix, that helps in monitoring hosts' resources and have automatic alarms etc. - for example disk exhaustion is a default alarm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve exactly what you want, you have to write your own stdout callback plugin.

Out of the box, there is `oneline` stdout plugin, you can apply it with `-o` or `--one-line` flag to `ansible` executable to get:

```
my_local | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) 116G
my_local2 | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) 116G
```