# Ansible ad-hoc task: How to separate output by host for clarity?

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

Is there a way to separate by host the output from a multi fork ad-hoc command?

I.e., if I ran:

```bash
ansible <group> -a '/some/cmd' -f 2
```

The result comes back as one long stream like

```bash
host1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Listing...
"some output"
host2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Listing...
"other output"
```

For clarity I would prefer the output with a gap between the output from each host like:

```bash
host1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Listing...
"some output"

host2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Listing...
"other output"
```

Even creating a script on the target that does an echo at the end and running that doesn't do it.

Comment: There's no easy way to do what you're asking. You could probably write a [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) to do what you want, but that's a big hammer. If you want to generate a human-readable report, consider writing  a playbook and generating the report with the `template` module.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same behavior that empty lines at the end gets removed. Since I have a similar requirement sometimes and depending on the task, I use the following approach

```bash
ansible test --user ${USER} --ask-pass --module-name shell --args "echo 'Output format test'; echo ' ';"
```

resulting in an output of

```bash
test1.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Output format test

test2.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Output format test
```

In other words, just add an `; echo ' ';` at the end.

Further information regarding output formatting can be found under

- [How to format Ansible output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439410/)
- [Ansible `stdout` formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009505/)
- [How can I get the output of Ansible ad-hoc command in JSON, CSV or other format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181910/)