# How to add specific facts to the content returned by Ansible ad-hoc?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

In the JSON  data returned by Ansible ad-hoc command, I noticed that there is `ansible_facts` in `{'event_data':'res':'ansible_facts':{'discovered_interpreter_python': '/usr/bin/python'}}`. It seems that no matter what module is executed, its output will be fixed with the `ansible_facts` variable `discovered_interpreter_python`.

I hope to add some other variables, such as `ansible_fqdn`, without requiring me to do extra operations.

Whether I execute ad-hoc or playbook, is it possible?

Comment: Does [Variable is undefined when running Ansible `debug` ad-hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74597905/6771046) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I read the link you sent, it seems to say that adhoc will not automatically collect facts, playbook can achieve what I want, but sometimes I just need a simple command execution, do not need to use playbook, but I It is hoped that the name of the host can be obtained in addition to the ip, so I am thinking that since discovered_interpreter_python can be used as a common return value, then fqdn should also be possible

Comment: "_adhoc will not automatically collect facts_", correct, that is the case. "_I am thinking that since discovered_interpreter_python can be used as a common return value, then fqdn should also be possible_", unfortunately not in that way.

Comment: Yeah, not everything goes my way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *... without requiring me to do extra operations. Whether I execute ad-hoc or playbook, is it possible?*

No, not as the requirement is written.

---

> *How to add some other variables, such as `ansible_fqdn`?*

Whereby via `ansible-playbook` and depending on the configuration [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) become gathered automatically, via `ansible` only and ad-hoc command not.

To do so you would need to execute the `setup` module instead, resulting into an output of

```json
ansible test -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_fqdn'
test.example.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_fqdn": "test.example.com",
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Variable is undefined when running Ansible `debug` ad-hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74597905/6771046)

---

> *How to add some other variables, such as `ansible_fqdn` ... whether I execute ... playbook*

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "network"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.fqdn }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Facts] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test.example.com
```

**Further Q&A**

- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)
- [Is it possible to gather only specific facts in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71692925/6771046)

---

Regarding your comment

> *I just need a simple command execution, do not need to use playbook, but I It is hoped that the name of the host can be obtained in addition to the IP ...*

What is possible with ad-hoc commands is to execute commands in chain and format the output in a simple way.

```yaml
ansible test --module-name shell --args "hostname; date; echo ' ';"
test1.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
test1.example.com 
Wed May 17 08:12:01 CEST 2023

test2.example.com  | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
test2.example.com 
Wed May 17 08:12:02 CEST 2023
```

If it is just the FQDN of the Remonte Node, it could be included within the command.

- [Ansible ad-hoc output: How to split every node result with new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70228752/6771046)